# How to "shutdown" or "disable" an HDMI port on Windows?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, wmi

My objective is **to power on my projector automatically**.

My projector can power on automatically :

- at computer startup (restart doesnt effect)
- plugin the HDMI cable (after unplug)

Windows+P doesn't power on the projector.

I hope that if I can disable/re-enable the HDMI port (simulate unplug/plug) then the projector power on. I want to do it by command line.

I didn't find any method on WMI classes: WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams, Win32_Desktopmonitor, Win32_VideoController

I can find the port like this

```
gwmi -class Win32_Portconnector | ? ExternalReferenceDesignator -like '*hdmi*'
```

Computer :

- Windows 10 x64
- Motherboard => Asus
- HDMI => projector
- VGA => LCD
- Graphic card => Intel HD 4400
- Drivers => 10.18.10.3650
- Screen mode => duplicate

Projector : Optoma WU334 (connected on MHL HDMI port).

Thanks for reading me